# prove the continuous and open

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the question

Suppose $E$ is a subset of $R$ and $f,g :E \rightarrow R$ 
are continuous on $E$.

Show that $\{x \in E : f(x) > g(x)\} $ is open

I'm confusing with this question.  what does $f(x) > g(x)$ have to do with the openness 
with continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It suffices to show $\{x:f(x) > 0\}$ is open when $f$ is continuous. The same set can be rewritten as $\{x:f(x) \in (0,\infty)\} = f^{-1}(0,\infty)$

Can you proceed from this?

Answer (score 1):

Choose $y\in\{x\in E | f(x)>g(x)\}$. Then $f(y)>g(y)$, i.e., $(f-g)(y)>0$. You also know that $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Can you now find a neighbourhood contained in $\{x\in E | f(x)>g(x)\}$ containing $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can show that the set $A=${$x\in E:f(x)\leq g(x)$} is closed.($A$ is complement of the set stated). Now use the sequence characterisation of continuity for $f$ and $g$.

But the easiest way in my opinion is Gautam Shenoy's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to show the following:

Given $x\in E$ with $f(x)>g(x)$ there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x')>g(x')$ for all $x'\in E$ with $|x-x'|<\varepsilon$.

Do you see that this is equivalent to the claim that the set from the problem is open? Can you prove the claim now?

(To everyone else: Yes, normally I too would prefer to just write the set as $(f-g)^{-1}[\dots]$.)

Comment: do since f(x')-g(x') < $\delta$ exist, there are p $\in N_\epsilon(fx) \cap N_epsilon(g(x) $??